# redirect_uri mismatch

Tags: rest-api

I am implementing an integration that will use the Sales Force REST API.

I am following this as reference:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US

The problem I'm having is on the second step, when I exchange the code for an access token.

I'm building it in Rails and this is where I make the POST request to get the token:

```
  def callback

    outbound_params = {
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => salesforce_consumer_key,
        'client_secret' => salesforce_consumer_secret,
        'redirect_uri' => url_encode(callback_url),
        'code' => params[:code],
        'format' => 'json'
    }

    x = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token'), outbound_params)

    render text: x.body
end
```

And it's returning:

```
{"error_description":"redirect_uri must match configuration","error":"redirect_uri_mismatch"}
```

I double checked the redirect_uri and it matches the one configured on the connected app config page.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Updated answer with points D-E]**

A few things to note here

A) It takes some time to propagate your connected app params (though Salesforce says it's 2-10 minutes, I've seen it take even longer in some cases) so you should re-test it. Also, double check that it's exactly the same (no single/ double slash difference)

B) There's a [bug](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000009Br4IAE) in the documentation which calls this param as request_url instead of request_uri (notice the difference in last character - 'l' vs. 'i'). This should not be a problem in your case as I see you are setting the correct parameter name.

C) You mentioned that this is in Rails. If you are developing it for a Heroku app, you need to set the relevant environment variables as mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000009BCCIA2).

D) Make sure that you your configured redirect URI and actual URL are both following the same protocol (http/ https).

E) Check if you are missing a trailing / in the re-direct URI, that could also lead to issues.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, but I've made the changes on the app 48h+ ago. The i/l should not be the problem as you saw in my code and I'm testing it locally for now. It's not going to be hosted on Heroku anyway.

Comment: Can you check for the protocol and trailing slash as well, I've updated my answer for the same - I've seen these causing issues many times

Comment: I did not have a trailing / on my redirect url configured. The protocol was already the same. I'm waiting for the changes to propagate to test again.